# Why does Kotlin composable only update after for loop is over?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to update a composable using mutableState inside a loop, but it only updates to the last value, after the loop finishes:

In Main.kt

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    var myClass = remember { MyClass() }
    MaterialTheme {
        Column() {
            Text(text="${myClass.myInt.value}")
            Button(onClick = myClass::run){ Text(text = "RUN") }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
class MyClass {
    val myInt = mutableStateOf(0)
    fun run(){
        for (i in 0..10){
            myInt.value = i
            Thread.sleep(500)
        }
    }
}
```

what am I missing? (I'm using Compose Desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` pauses execution of your thread for the time given. Since you're calling it on the UI thread, it pauses all rendering and updating of any views in the whole app until it's done, so you'll never see any changes until the whole loop is done. Since it freezes the UI, it puts your app at risk of being shut down for not responding (ANR error).

You can do this using a coroutine and `delay()`, but you need to make it a suspend function. My apologies if there are any mistakes below, as I don't have any experience with Compose.

```
class MyClass {
    val myInt = mutableStateOf(0)
    suspend fun run(){
        for (i in 0..10){
            myInt.value = i
            delay(500)
        }
    }
}

// Main.kt:
@Composable
fun App() {
    var myClass = remember { MyClass() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    MaterialTheme {
        Column() {
            Text(text="${myClass.myInt.value}")
            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { myClass.run() }) { 
                Text(text = "RUN") 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I would never have know you had no compose experience.